# Can't start new jquery functions during drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I noticed that the CSS hover function doesn't trigger when dragging an element from outside the page. I wanted to have a "drop it here" div that lights up when the mouse is over it, but hover didn't work and neither does this:

```
    // Cosmetic thing
    $('#dropzone').on({
        dragover: function(e) {
            $('#dropzone').addClass('on');
        },
        dragleave: function(e) {
            $('#dropzone').removeClass('on');
        }
    });
```

I can see in the inspector the class IS being added, but it doesn't light up.

I also tried closing my popup drop area, with a mousemove event while dragging, but the event doesn't seem to work until after I let go of the mouse:

```
        $(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
            console.log('x:'+e.pageX+' y:'+e.pageY);
            if (e.pageX <= 0 || e.pageX > $(document).width() || e.pageY <= 0 || e.pageY > $(document).height())
            {
                dropperOff();
                $(document).unbind('mousemove');
            }
        });
```

Lastly I tried to just have a constant mousemove tracking event that populates a mouseX and mouseY variable at all times. When I move the mouse, it works fine, but the moment a dragenter event fires, the mousemove event stops working too.

This behavior is making it very hard to make the page work. Is there a way around this or do I have to give up on making my dropzone light up and detect when the drag event leaves the page?

Comment: Is that 'the' dropzone.js ?

Comment: No. Just a div with the ID "dropzone"

Comment: Well, what's your CSS? If your class is being added properly, that would be the next logical place to look.

Comment: #dropzone .on,#dropzone:hover {
       border   : 5px dotted #aaa;
       background  : #555;
      }